New to ubuntu having no sound
I have tried several methods to try get my sound back but it has either failed since im dumb at linux or it doesnt work
I transfured to ubuntu from windows 11 on a geobook 140 now im stuck with no sound coming out of speakers or even a headset and i cannot do a method without me messing sanc up
Version:22.04.4
OS type: 64-bit

Please give Ubuntu 23.10 a try. Usually recent versions of Ubuntu work better with recent hardware.

Have you got the PulseAudio package and the package for pulseAudio volume control?

I believe i have the pulseaudio packages
